# MySQL: обновить записи для прошедшей даты

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть таблица `users` с множеством строк. в ней есть поле `date2`. Нужно сделать такой запрос, который задаст поле `payed=0`, дата в поле `date2` уже прошла, то есть сравнить с текущей датой. Спасибо.

29-5-2014 дата в таком формате

я так пытался сделать

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT date2 FROM users");
$json = array();
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $date=$r;
    if (time() > $date) {
    }
}
```

В общем я сделал даты в формате `date()`, но теперь как же все таки сравнивать даты?

Comment: Какой тип поля date2?

Comment: varchar, а дата в таком формате 29-5-2014

Comment: @Jenya Kirmiza, в таком случае первое, с чего нужно начать - `alter table ...` :-) И изменить `varchar` на что-то более осмысленное.

Comment: если я сделаю Date, то можно будет записать строку "29-5-2014" в это поле? не будет ошибки из-за формата?

Comment: Ошибки не будет, но существующие даты сбросятся в '0000-00-00' (потому что формат не тот). Поэтому сначала:

    update `users` set `date2` = str_to_date(`date2`, '%d-%m-%Y');


Потом уже менять тип поля. И писать уже потом в таблицу по-человечески, то есть в формате 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

Comment: не понял. может сразу поменять таблицу через alter table, а потом уже делать str_to_date('date2','%Y-%m-%d')?

Comment: Наоборот. Сначала привести существующие строки в правильный для даты формат, потом уже менять тип поля через alter. Иначе потеряете значения.

Comment: понял. проверю

Answer (score 2):

Задачу проще всего бы решить средствами MySQL, в которой очень богатая библиотека календарных функций, позволяющая осуществлять с датами любые операции. Однако, чтобы воспользоваться ими, необходимо чтобы дата была представлена календарным типом. Т.е. все данные в `date2` должны быть представлены в формате 2014-05-29.

Тогда для решения задачи можно было бы воспользоваться запросом

```
UPDATE
  users
SET
  payed = 0
WHERE
  date2 < '2014-05-29';
```

Один из способов решения возникшей проблемы состоит в преобразовании текущего формата данных в календарный

```
UPDATE
  users
SET
  date2 = STR_TO_DATE(date2, '%e-%c-%Y');
```

Этот запрос переведет даты в формате '29-5-2014' в '2014-05-29'. В принципе после этого можно пользоваться первым запросом, так как строки сравниваются слева направо. Однако, лучше преобразовать еще и тип столбца в `DATE`, для этого можно воспользоваться следующим ALTER-запросом

```
ALTER TABLE
  users
CHANGE
  date2 date2 DATE NOT NULL;
```

Так как даты уже приведены к формату `DATE` данные будут успешно сохранены после ALTER-преобразования.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно стоит использовать `CURDATE()`:

```
UPDATE users SET payed=0 WHERE CURDATE()>date2
```

[CURDATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)